# Different UI's sharing same BLL and DAL

Tags: .net, data-access-layer, bll

We've written a system using a tiered UI, BLL, DAL architecture.

We now need to write a website which utilises the same database and will use up to 50% of the existing system BLL and DAL.

I don't want to create a separate solution and 'copy and paste' the BLL and DAL because as changes are made many will have to be replicated across both solutions.

I considered giving the website its own BLL and DAL and referencing the compiled system DLL's to remove the duplication, but I fear that may prove to be impractical since there would often be updates to both solutions.

I would like to keep the two projects logically separate if possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add another project to the solution, the website project, and have it reference the BLL and DAL projects?

Nothing stops you from having a web application, a WPF app, 2 class libraries and even a Silverlight app in the same solution!

So your solution would end up like:

```
--Solution  
  |  
  --- Main appp  
  |  
  --- BLL  
  |  
  --- DAL  
  |  
  --- Web App
```

Comment: How would I then set this up as two separate websites on the same server? Or would I just have to configure the WebApp folder as a separate application?

Comment: Exactly. HAving them on the same solution is just a means to share some DLLs. The 2 websites will happily (and automatically) operate completely independently from each other.